# How do I convert epoch format date to PostgreSQL database date (timestamp without time zone) in DAO implementation class or vice versa

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, web-services, spring-rest

I am giving input to Spring REST api as epoch format in String (eg "1478607386").After that, I passed this data from Controller to DAOImplementation class and then, I fetched  a column data having data type timestamp without time zone from PostgreSQL in same DAO class.Now I need to compare both data ie. epoch format data which is in String format(eg "1478607386") and database data from PostgreSQL which is in timestamp without time zone format(i am able to store this data in List variable form in DAOImplementation) whether they are of same date or not.Can any one help me how to do that.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can extract the epoch in PostgreSQL and compare the result in Java.

To extract the epoch as `bigint`, you can proceed like this:

```
SELECT CAST (extract(epoch FROM timestampcol) AS bigint) FROM mytable WHERE ...;
```

Alternatively, you can retrieve the timestamp as [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) and use [`java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis()) to extract the epoch in Java.

Comment: @Laorenz Albe Thanks for your response.I cant update the database.I just need to convert epoch (String or unix timestamps) to Database Timestamp without time zone format in java class to check whether they are equals or not. Or In other way you can take it as converting Database Timestamp without time zone to String Date(similar to epoch date format ) for comparision in java class. Hope you understand my issue friend :)

Comment: It is still unclear. Please edit the question and describe in more detail what you actually want. I understand that you want to write something in Java, so using that tag might help. Explain what you mean by *database timestamp* provide an example of what the desired code would do.

Comment: I elaborate the problem more precisely.Hope it is understandable now.

Comment: Your querry will work at database level,but i need such sort of result in java DAOImplementation class using Hibernate Query Language.

Comment: Hello Albe,I wana this " select DATE(row_created) from sometable " query into  hibernate query language.Thanks